# Pass control prop to child component in react hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to pass the `control` prop to my custom component that comes from `react-hook-form` but it tells that the `control` is `undefined`

I did the same thing written in document. I used `FormProvider` like this:

```
<FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form
          style={{
            height: "auto",
            width: "90%",
            padding: "2em",
            paddingTop: "0",
            textAlign: "center",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            borderRadius: "10px",
          }}
          onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}
        >
          <IconButton
            color="error"
            onClick={() => setRecordControl({ stat: "" })}
          >
            <Cancel fontSize="large" />
          </IconButton>
          <h3 style={{ marginBottom: "10px", textAlign: "center" }}>
            saving records
          </h3>
          {filtered.ListColumnInfo.map(
            (detail) =>
              detail.VisibleColumn && (
                <div key={uuidV4()}>
                  <CustomTextBoxComponent
                    filtered={detail}
                  />
                </div>
              )
          )}

          <Button
            variant="contained"
            fullWidth
            color="success"
            sx={{ mt: "1em" }}
            type="submit"
          >
            save
          </Button>
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
```

and I tried to retrieve the `control` inside of my `CustomTextBoxComponent` like this:

```
const CustomTextBoxComponent = ({ filtered }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <Controller
      name="input"
      render={({ field }) => (
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          placeholder={
            filtered.ElsRecord.PersianName !== ""
              ? filtered.ElsRecord.PersianName
              : filtered.ElsRecord.Name
          }
    
          sx={{ marginBlock: "1em" }}
          {...control}
          {...field}
        />
      )}
      defaultValue=""
    />
  );
};
```

it didn't work. always says the method is `null`

[the picture of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiu5J.png)

how can I solve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you make a running example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/new